# SWT Composite appears on the right

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I am developing an plugin for eclipse with a view, I need to make this view scrollable. I found how to make it scrollable, but the composite appears on the right side of view. How to fill all view?

My code:

```
public class Comp2 extends Composite {

    public Comp2(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);

        final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        sc.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);

        final Composite subContainer = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(subContainer, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setBounds(75, 99, 90, 30);
        btnNewButton.setText("New Button");

        Button btnNewButton_1 = new Button(subContainer, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(357, 398, 90, 30);
        btnNewButton_1.setText("New Button");

        sc.setContent(subContainer);

        sc.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                Rectangle r = sc.getClientArea();
                sc.setMinSize(subContainer
                        .computeSize(r.width, SWT.DEFAULT));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }
}
```

[image: my view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are extending `Composite` the composite is adding its normal body to the parent. You are then adding a `ScrolledComposite` to the **parent** so it sits alongside that first composite.

You can put the `ScrollComposite` inside the `Composite` by changing its parent:

```java
super(parent, SWT.NONE);

// This composite needs a layout
setLayout(new FillLayout());

// Parent of the ScrolledComposite is this Composite
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(this, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

Comment: Thank's! Now it's ok!